# Extracting the return type of a function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to get a reference to the return type of a function in TypeScript.  More specifically, I want to do this so that I can obtain a reference to an implicitly defined type returned from a function.

Here is an example of what I'm after.  The following are two separate files.  The first one compiles properly; the second does not.  It demonstrates what I would like to be able to do, but don't know how to accomplish.

**wrapName.ts**

```
function wrapName(name:string) {
  return { getName: () { return name; };
}

export = wrapName
```

**app.ts**

```
import wrapName = require("./wrapName");
var name = wrapName("Viper");
var NameWrapper = typeof(name);
fn1(name);

function fn1(name:NameWrapper):string {
  return name.getName();
}
```

I recognize that I could do this by explicitly declaring NameWrapper, but I would love to avoid having to do that if possible, simply allowing the caller to use whatever it is handed by the function.

Answer (score 1):

First `wrapName.ts` had a few syntax errors, fixed version:

```
function wrapName(name: string) {
    return {
        getName: () => {
            return name;
        }
    };
}

export = wrapName;
```

Now for your usage. I haven't found a way to create a new alias (`NameWrapper`) for `typeof foo`. But you can just use `typeof foo` itself:

```
import wrapName = require("./wrapName");

var NameWrapper = wrapName("Viper");

fn1(NameWrapper);

function fn1(name: typeof NameWrapper): string {
    return name.getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using functions rather than types (javascript is a functional language after all and function are first class citizens)

```
function wrapName(name:string): () => string {
    return () => { return name }
}





function fn1(wrapper:()=> string):string {
    return wrapper()
}

var wrapper = wrapName("Viper")
console.log(fn1(wrapper))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed the `NameWrapper` declaration. It is a `type`, not a `var`.

**wrapName.ts**

```
function wrapName(name: string) {
    return {
        getName: () => { return name; }
    }
}

export = wrapName;
```

**app.ts**

```
import wrapName = require("./wrapName");
var name = wrapName("Viper");
type NameWrapper = typeof name; // <-- change 'var' to 'type'
fn1(name);

function fn1(name: NameWrapper): string {
    return name.getName();
}
```